# Jquery append option in select tag

Tags: php, jquery, sql, ajax

Here i tried as much i can but couldn't get results. please any guys help me out.
i cannot get the correct result using these codes.may be something i'm missing.

```
$get_medical_aod_name = $_POST['name'];
$select_query = mysql_query("SELECT id, name FROM insurance_companies WHERE cat=$get_medical_aod_name");
while ($row = mysql_fetch_array($select_query)) {
  $result[] = array(
    'id' => $row['id'],
    'name' => $row['name']
  );
}
header('Content-Type: application/json', true);
echo json_encode($result);
```

and in my script.js

```
$('#medical_aid_name').change(function(){
       //alert("working");
       var name = $(this).val();
       $.post('ins_bene.php',
    {'name' : name },
    function(data){
        var select = $('#benefit').empty();
        $.each(data.values, function(i,data) {
            select.append( '<option value="'
                                 + data.id
                                 + '">'
                                 + data.name
                                 + '</option>' ); 
        });
    }, "json");
   });
```

and i feel everything fine but i'm getting no output :(

Comment: What does "no output" mean? Does the select element get cleared with the `.empty()` statement?

Comment: yes, select element get cleared.

Comment: no, im not getting results.

Comment: print name first, make sure that name is non empty string, and once try the query with name in editor.

Comment: have a look at my answer that should work

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this... **UPDATED**

```
    $('#medical_aid_name').change(function() {
        var name = $(this).val();
        $.post('ins_bene.php', { 'name': name },
        function(data) {
            alert(data)  // [object][object],[object][object]
            $('#benefit').empty();
            $.each(data, function(key, value) {
                $('#benefit').append('<option value="' + value.id + '">' + value.name + '</option>');
            });
        }, "json");
    });
```

Comment: how this is answer to the question

Comment: that is global variable that wont clear, try it yourself first

Comment: <select id="benefit"> </select> remains empty by var select = $('#benefit').empty();

Comment: @Stoppie Chandru DiGi  Sorry no need of `var select = $('#benefit').empty();`. just use `$('#benefit').empty();` I dont know php. But in jQuery its the way to append value to listbox.

Comment: @Stoppie Chandru Check using alert(data);. U should get [object][object]. If u didnt get anything then check ur mysql function

Comment: empty select tag without options

Comment: @Lakshmana Kumar i'm getting [object Object],[object Object] in alert(data)

Comment: @Stoppie Chandru DiGi   So wats the problem u got?

Answer (score 1):

You need to quote the query:

```
$select_query = mysql_query("SELECT id, name FROM insurance_companies WHERE cat=$get_medical_aod_name");
```

to

```
$select_query = mysql_query('SELECT id, name FROM insurance_companies WHERE cat="' . mysql_real_escape_string($get_medical_aod_name) .'"');
```

Please don't use mysql_ functions. Move to PDO!

Comment: after quote the query, select element is not getting cleared and getting empty select.

Answer (score 0):

Instead of the following code:

```
 var select = $('#benefit').empty();
        $.each(data.values, function(i,data) {
            select.append( '<option value="'
                                 + data.id
                                 + '">'
                                 + data.name
                                 + '</option>' ); 
        });
```

Use the below code:

```
    var select = $('#benefit').empty();
    $.each(data.values, function(i,data) {
        $('#benefit').append( '<option value="'
                             + data[i].id
                             + '">'
                             + data[i].name
                             + '</option>' ); 
    });
```

Here select var don't have the object of the select tag that's why.

Comment: he is not even getting results

Comment: @kongaraju how can you say that he is not getting the result.

Comment: look at my comments on question

Comment: @kongaraju he don't say anything regards it.

Comment: @StoppieChandruDiGi can you show the result of `alert(JSON.stringify(data));` here so that i can help you much better. use this alert before the each function.

Comment: thanks for your help, it works fine now. codes by @LakshmanaKumar.

Answer (score 0):

Change this in script.js

```
$.each(data.values, function(key, value)
```

to

```
$.each(data, function(key, value) {
```

OR

Assign a key `values` to `$result`

```
while ($row = mysql_fetch_array($select_query)) {
  $result['values'] = array(
    'id' => $row['id'],
    'name' => $row['name']
  );
}
```

Answer (score 0):

this should work

```
while ($row = mysql_fetch_array($select_query)) {
  $result['values'] = array(
    'id' => $row['id'],
    'name' => $row['name']
  );
}
```